# Is it possible to use React native for steam?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, steam

is it possible to create a react native app and publish it on steam?

Does someone knowd projects which are used for steam games?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout electron and react-desktop.

https://www.electronjs.org/apps?category=games
https://github.com/gabrielbull/react-desktop

Answer (score 0):

react-native is used to develop webview mobile application. That's why it's not possible to make a game that you can play on steam. However, it is possible to develop various mobile applications. You can check Electronjs and etc for develop desktop app but if you want to develop games for steam, my advice to you is to use game engines like Unity.

Comment: Im not too familiar with WebView apps, but I assume that they are essential web views with html/css/js provided to them. If thats true, then React Native isnt a WebView app. While React Native uses JSX that could be mistaken for html, under the hood that JSX is being used to create native versions of that JSX. There is even a WebView component that you can access with react native

Comment: Actually yes, you are right. It basically allows us to develop native components, but with expo and other packages this is possible. In this post, it was wrong to put it directly under the heading 'webview'. However, it would be better to turn to alternatives as a result.